# insertar contenido en tabla con dos columnas, cuando se llene un td, el resto se ponga en otro td DomPDF

Tags: php, jquery, css, table, dompdf

Me encuentro generando contenido con Dompdf y codeigniter, obtengo texto e imagenes de un array mediante un foreach y voy agregando el contenido a una variable,y la idea es insertarlo en dos columnas, en las cuales primero se llene una y el resto se vaya a la otra columna, y en caso de que exista mas contenido se genere otro tr y se vaya mostrando el contenido sobrante, obviamente tengo que definir el heigth y width de la tabla.
Al imprimirlo normal se ve correcto, pero al cambiarlo para pdf no me respeta las dos columnas ni el salto de pagina. intenté cortar la cadena generada, pero me cortaba los tags html o las url de las imagenes,

```
<?php
  $string = ""; //genero variable para ir almacenando todos los datos obtenidos
  foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {
    for ($i=0; $i < count($value) ; $i++) {
    $string .= "<p>".$value->area."</p>";  
    $desc = $value->descripcion;
    if(isset($desc) && !empty($desc)){
      $string .= "<br>".$desc."</br>";
    }
    if($value->image){ //si existe imagen la agregamos dentro de una tabla ya que se salia de un <td>
      foreach ($value->image as $k => $img) {
        $string.= '<table border="1"><tr><td><img style="max-width: 180px; max-height: 200px;" src="'.FCPATH.$img['url'].'"/></td></tr></table>';
      }
    }
  }
}
   ?>
  <table width="100%" style="padding: 0px 50px 0 50px; page-break-before: always;">
    <tr>
        <?php
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<div  style='column-count: 2;'>";
            echo $string;
            echo "</div>";
            echo '</td>';
         ?>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

actualizando, modifique la parte donde muestro el contenido de la variable y me muestra las dos columnas, pero cuando hay imagenes no tengo manera de darle salto de tr al llegar al limite de height, desafortunadamente str_split me corta la url de la imagen, como podria contar el heigth para darle un salto de tr?

```
<table border="1" width="100%" style=" page-break-before: always;">
<tr>
    <?php
    $rep =1;
      $splited = str_split($var,1600);
      foreach ($splited as $key => $sp) {
        echo '<td style="height: 450;width:180;" >';
        echo $sp;
        echo '</td>';
        echo ($rep%2==0)?'</tr><tr>':' ';
        $rep++;
      }
     ?>  
</tr>
```

Comment: gracias, ya eliminé la otra

Comment: vale, gracias... ahora las malas noticias... tal como está tu pregunta puede ser cerrada pronto porque no tiene un [example] y las preguntas de código sin código no son bien recibidas pues dan la sensación que nos mandas una tarea, lo siento.  Por otra parte, esto no es un foro y no se dan opiniones ni recomendaciones, sino que se intenta solucionar un problema concreto y especifico, delimitado por el [example], y por último, las preguntas deben ser concretas, y no varias a la vez, pues también es motivo de cierre, lo siento. Léete [ask] y [tour] también para ver como funcionamos, gracias

Comment: enterado, agradezco tu tiempo para ayudarme a plantear mi problema, modificare la pregunta con la parte de codigo, y revisaré https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por tu colaboración. Piensa que las preguntas son cerradas con 3 votos de cierre, y de momento aún no llevas ninguno y estás a tiempo de modificarla para que eso no suceda, esa es la actitud :-)

Comment: no se si ayudará, no creo, pero a esto le faltan las unidades: `style="height: 450;width:180;"` (entiendo que son **px** en ambas pero no estoy tan seguro si el interprete lo entiende así también o pasa de esos valores)

Comment: de hecho le quité el height y width porque lo estaba forzando al darle esas medidas, al quitarselas me repeta el tamaño de las imagenes y no las corta, pero no me respeta las dos columnas, solo imprime en una cuando es generado el pdf

Comment: pero las dos columnas las estas haciendo con ese `column-count`?  Yo en los PDF siempre uso tablas y evito CSS porque me dan problemas, pero no uso DomPDF, sino un programa de linux que hay para eso, pero no me extrañaria que fuera un problema común. La verdad es que nunca habia visto el `column-count` y me parece muy interesante, lo probaré algun dia.

Comment: el column-count lo uso mas en los divs, y si, como mencionas en los pdf tambien uso pura tablas